# how to remove imported css in create-react-app?

Tags: create-react-app

In my content.tsx file I have:

```
import style from 'style.css';
```

The CSS file is imported and appended to head when the page is loaded which is fine, but is there a way to remove this style from DOM inside the same content.tsx?

`console.log(style)` only shows a empty object.

Comment: Facing the same problem. I still didn't found how to properly unload CSS or a workaround to do this. Did you?

Comment: So... I guess you haven't found any solution yet

Answer (score -1):

Just remove `import style from 'style.css';` from your component if you don't want to include the CSS

Comment: So... once a style is imported, there's no way to remove it from DOM?
Obviously i can do a page refresh, but in that scenario, all other styles will disappear.